# What does following code mean in assignment to STACK variable

Tags: shell

```
STACK="${2:-}"
shift
;;
```

What does the following code mean in shell script?
Specifically what does `${2:-}` mean? Looks like it is assigned to a variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between :- and := in Bash parameter substitution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218775/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash-parameter-substitution)

Comment: Please read the section about *parameter expansion* of your shell (maybe `man sh` does the trick). It's all explained in there, with all variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${2:-}` means, if the `2nd` parameter is unset or null, empty will be assigned to it.
Eg:

```
$ a=         # passed empty to a
$ echo $a    # prints empty or nothing

$ echo ${a:-test}  # prints test
test
```